# Why is dynamic_cast considered bad practice in C++?

Tags: c#, c++, dynamic-cast

I know there is quite a few questions along these lines already, but I still don't understand. Take for example:

```
class Projectile
{
   public:
    virtual void OnCollision(Projectile& other);

   private:
    Vector position;
    Vector velocity;
};
class Bullet : Projectile
{
    // We may want to execute different code based on the type of projectile
    // "other" is.
    void OnCollision(Projectile& other) override;
};
class Rocket : Projectile
{
    // If other is a bullet, we might want the rocket to survive the collision,
    // otherwise if it's a rocket, we may want both to explode.
    void OnCollision(Projectile& other) override;
};
```

I don't understand how this example could be done without dynamic_cast. We can't rely on just a polymorphic interface, because that will only provide us with information about one object in this case. Is there a way this can be done without dynamic_cast?

Also, why isn't dynamic casts considered bad practice in C#? They're used ALL the time throughout event handlers and non-generic containers. A lot of what can be done in C# relies on casts.

Comment: why there is the `c++` tag ?

Comment: @user2485710 Because dynamic_cast is c++ and so is my example.

Comment: ok, from the look of it, I was going to say that this was a C# only question, so your question is about both languages.

Comment: @user2485710 Why did you remove the spacing...?

Comment: Your title says `why is` but in your post you say `why isn't`. Which are you asking? And who says dynamic_casts are bad practice?

Comment: For most you need dynamic_cast in C#, you can do it with templates and inheritance in C++. Still, double dispatch needs it even in C++.

Comment: what do you need spacing for ? I also fixed your class declarations with the final `;` and indented your code to the canonical 80 columns .

Comment: @Daniel Fixed the title.

Comment: @Ben Your title doesn't appear to have changed... Please also post your source for why it is/isn't bad practice.

Comment: I think that is safe to say that this is a duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dynamic+cast+bad , there are already good answers here on SO, the only thing that I think I can add as a side comment is that this kind of cast requires RTTI and this can be considered a let down in some cases.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [double dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_dispatch)?

Comment: Note on C# - if using cast good or bad is somewhat personal choice, your samples seem to be not very useful - "used all the time ... non-generic containers" - no one really cares that much about this case as using strongly typed containers is so much easier and we are long way from 1.0 version of CLR/C#. Similar about event handler - it often easier to just use strongly typed value with Lambda and ignore `source` completely...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this specific example, I would have added a protected method:

```
protected:
   virtual int getKickassNess() = 0;

// Bullet:
   int getKickassNess() override { return 10; }
// Rocket:
   int getKickassNess() override { return 9001; }  // over 9000!

void Bullet::OnCollision(Projectile& other)
{
   if (other.getKickassNess() > this->getKickassNess())
      // wimp out and die
}
```

IMO Bullet and Rocket should not know that each other exist. Putting in these kinds of knows-about relationships often make things difficult, and in this specific case I can imagine it causing messy cyclic include issues.

Comment: So, I should have the objects behave based on their properties rather than their type? That makes a lot of sense. Thanks.